# Difference between Load event,Activate event and Enter event in the Form

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I am using VB.NET for Windows applications. What is the difference between Load event,Activate event and Enter event in the Form and in which order the above event is executed.Please anyone help me.

Sivakumar.P

Answer (score 9):

See the [Windows Forms Events Lifecycle](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mamta_m/WindowsFormsLifecycle11182008235227PM/WindowsFormsLifecycle.aspx) for info.

Comment: This link may break in the future. Please update this answer to include the most critical pieces of information.

Answer (score 3):

The Enter event is suppressed in Form. Its equivalent is Activated. Loaded occurs once during creation. Activated occurs whenever the Form becomes active (e.g. is selected by the user, opened, etc). Loaded comes before Activated.

Answer (score 0):

Load: This event occurs before a form is displayed for the first time.

Activated: This event occurs when the form is activated in code or by the user.